# How to use numpy with 'None' value in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I'd like to calculate the mean of an array in Python in this form:

```
Matrice = [1, 2, None]
```

I'd just like to have my `None` value ignored by the `numpy.mean` calculation but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: +1: this question can be particularly relevant for arrays that are imported from a database, where values can sometimes be NULL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).  Here's an example.

```
import numpy.ma as ma
a = ma.array([1, 2, None], mask = [0, 0, 1])
print "average =", ma.average(a)
```

From the numpy docs linked above, "The numpy.ma module provides a nearly work-alike replacement for numpy that supports data arrays with masks."

Comment: a member function that helped a lot was `filled`.  that brought the masked array back to a normal array, filled with a value that I would recognize as invalid (NaN, -9999, whatever your users need).

Comment: Performance of masked arrays is also significantly less than regular numpy arrays as the implementation is pure Python. If you are dealing with big data, be aware of the performance implications.

Comment: Better to use numpy.nanmean than looking for ad-hoc solutions outside of numpy; see answer below.

Comment: Masked arrays are not ad-hoc nor outside of numpy. The docs link in my answer shows this.

Answer (score 7):

haven't used numpy, but in standard python you can filter out `None` using list comprehensions
 or the filter function

```
>>> [i for i in [1, 2, None] if i != None]
[1, 2]
>>> filter(lambda x: x != None, [1, 2, None])
[1, 2]
```

and then average the result to ignore the `None`

Comment: `x != None` is usually written `x is not None` (PEP 8: "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators.")

Answer (score 6):

You can use scipy for that:

```
import scipy.stats.stats as st
m=st.nanmean(vec)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.   `a = [1,2,None]` and then `st.nanmean(a)` results in a TypeError.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works on numpy.nan, not on None. It's most useful when calculating the mean on numpy vector.

Comment: Now you can use also numpy.nanmean

Answer (score 4):

You might also be able to kludge with values like NaN or Inf.

```
In [1]: array([1, 2, None])
Out[1]: array([1, 2, None], dtype=object)

In [2]: array([1, 2, NaN])
Out[2]: array([  1.,   2.,  NaN])
```

Actually, it might not even be a kludge.  [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> NaNs may be used to represent missing values in computations.

Actually, this doesn't work for the mean() function, though, so nevermind.  :)

```
In [20]: mean([1, 2, NaN])
Out[20]: nan
```

Comment: Actually, `mean(a[~isnan(a)])` explicitly choosing all non-NaN values works.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use filter, pass None to it, it will filter non True objects, also 0, :D
So, use it when you dont need 0 too.

```
>>> filter(None,[1, 2, None])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can 'upcast' the array to numpy's float64 dtype and then use numpy's nanmean method as in the following example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [1,2,3, None]
arr2 = np.array(arr, dtype=np.float64)
print(arr2) # [ 1.  2.  3. nan]
print(np.nanmean(arr2)) # 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

np.mean(Matrice[Matrice != None])