# numpy index slice with None

Tags: python, numpy

Working through a [sliding-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python/30110497#30110497) example for numpy. Was trying to understand the `,None` of `start_idx = np.arange(B[0])[:,None]`

```
foo = np.arange(10)
print foo
print foo[:]
print foo[:,]
print foo[:,None]
```

The effect of the `None` seems to be to transpose the array.

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]
 [8]
 [9]]
```

But I'm not totally sure.  I haven't been able to find the documentation that explains what the second parameter (`None`) does.  It's a hard fragment to google for, too.  The [numpy array docs makes me think it has something to do with advanced indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962343/how-to-use-numpy-with-none-value-in-python), but I'm not sure enough.

Comment: It's used as an alias for [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) here being used to add singleton dimensions (dims with length=1). In the sample case, it was added to convert the input 1D array to `2D` with the second dim being singleton.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`foo[:, None]` extends the 1 dimensional array `foo` into the second dimension.  In fact, `numpy` uses the alias `np.newaxis` to do this.

consider `foo`

```
foo = np.array([1, 2])
print(foo)

[1 2]
```

A one dimensional array has limitations.  For example, what's the transpose?

```
print(foo.T)

[1 2]
```

The same as the array itself

```
print(foo.T == foo)

[ True True]
```

This limitation has many implications and it becomes useful to consider `foo` in higher dimensional context.  numpy uses `np.newaxis`

```
print(foo[np.newaxis, :])

[[1 2]]
```

But this `np.newaxis` is just syntactic sugar for `None`

```
np.newaxis is None

True
```

So, often we use `None` instead because it's less characters and means the same thing

```
print(foo[None, :])

[[1 2]]
```

---

Ok, let's see what else we could've done.  Notice I used the example with `None` in the first position while OP use the second position.  This position specifies which dimension is extended.  And we could've taken that further.  Let these examples help explain

```
print(foo[None, :])  # same as foo.reshape(1, 2)

[[1 2]]
```

---

```
print(foo[:, None])  # same as foo.reshape(2, 1)

[[1]
 [2]]
```

---

```
print(foo[None, None, :])  # same as foo.reshape(1, 1, 2) 

[[[1 2]]]
```

---

```
print(foo[None, :, None])  # same as foo.reshape(1, 2, 1)

[[[1]
  [2]]]
```

---

```
print(foo[:, None, None])  # same as foo.reshape(2, 1, 1)

[[[1]]

 [[2]]]
```

---

Keep in mind which dimension is which when numpy prints the array

```
print(np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3))

          dim2        
          ────────⇀
dim0 →  [[[ 0  1  2]   │ dim1
          [ 3  4  5]   │
          [ 6  7  8]]  ↓
          ────────⇀
     →   [[ 9 10 11]   │
          [12 13 14]   │
          [15 16 17]]  ↓
          ────────⇀
     →   [[18 19 20]   │
          [21 22 23]   │
          [24 25 26]]] ↓
```